# How to disable Visual Studio 2015 and above automatic bower install on solution load?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm, bower, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I open the solution in Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 RC it starts automatically running bower install on one of the projects. The bower install output can be seen in the `Bower/NPM` output under the Output view:

```
PATH=X:\iis\wwwroot\LeExampleProjectName\.\node_modules\.bin;%PATH%
"C:\Users\PC118\AppData\Roaming\npm\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
bower angular#1.3.14            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.14
bower angular#1.3.14          validate 1.3.14 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.14
bower bootstrap#3.3.2           cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.2
bower bootstrap#3.3.2         validate 3.3.2 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.2
bower moment#~2.10.3            cached git://github.com/moment/moment.git#2.10.6
bower moment#~2.10.3          validate 2.10.6 against git://github.com/moment/moment.git#~2.10.3
bower angular-sanitize#1.3.14   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.3.14
bower angular-sanitize#1.3.14 validate 1.3.14 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.3.14
bower lodash#3.3.1              cached git://github.com/lodash/lodash.git#3.3.1
bower lodash#3.3.1            validate 3.3.1 against git://github.com/lodash/lodash.git#3.3.1
bower angular-ui-select#~0.12.0 cached git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select.git#0.12.1
bower angular-ui-select#~0.12.0         validate 0.12.1 against git://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select.git#~0.12.0
bower angular-animate#1.3.14              cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.3.14
bower angular-animate#1.3.14            validate 1.3.14 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.3.14
bower angular-strap#2.2.0                 cached git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap.git#2.2.0
bower angular-strap#2.2.0               validate 2.2.0 against git://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap.git#2.2.0
bower selectize#0.8.5                     cached git://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js.git#0.8.5
bower selectize#0.8.5                   validate 0.8.5 against git://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js.git#0.8.5
bower microplugin#0.0.x                   cached git://github.com/brianreavis/microplugin.js.git#0.0.3
bower microplugin#0.0.x                 validate 0.0.3 against git://github.com/brianreavis/microplugin.js.git#0.0.x
bower jquery#>=0.6.0                      cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#>=0.6.0                    validate 2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>=0.6.0
bower sifter#0.3.x                        cached git://github.com/brianreavis/sifter.js.git#0.3.4
bower sifter#0.3.x                      validate 0.3.4 against git://github.com/brianreavis/sifter.js.git#0.3.x
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1                     cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1                   validate 2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.1
bower lodash#3.3.1                       install lodash#3.3.1
bower moment#~2.10.3                     install moment#2.10.6
bower angular-sanitize#1.3.14            install angular-sanitize#1.3.14
bower angular-ui-select#~0.12.0          install angular-ui-select#0.12.1
bower angular#1.3.14                     install angular#1.3.14
bower selectize#0.8.5                    install selectize#0.8.5
bower angular-animate#1.3.14             install angular-animate#1.3.14
bower microplugin#0.0.x                  install microplugin#0.0.3
bower sifter#0.3.x                       install sifter#0.3.4
bower angular-strap#2.2.0                install angular-strap#2.2.0
bower bootstrap#3.3.2                    install bootstrap#3.3.2
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1                    install jquery#2.1.4
lodash#3.3.1 bower_components\lodash
moment#2.10.6 bower_components\moment
angular-sanitize#1.3.14 bower_components\angular-sanitize
└── angular#1.3.14
angular-ui-select#0.12.1 bower_components\angular-ui-select
└── angular#1.3.14
angular#1.3.14 bower_components\angular
selectize#0.8.5 bower_components\selectize
├── jquery#2.1.4
├── microplugin#0.0.3
└── sifter#0.3.4
angular-animate#1.3.14 bower_components\angular-animate
└── angular#1.3.14
microplugin#0.0.3 bower_components\microplugin
sifter#0.3.4 bower_components\sifter
angular-strap#2.2.0 bower_components\angular-strap
└── angular#1.3.14
bootstrap#3.3.2 bower_components\bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.4
jquery#2.1.4 bower_components\jquery
```

Is there a way to disable this automatic bower install? And other ways to configure it?

Comment: did you manage to fix this issue? Im also experiencing this

Comment: @LincAbela I did not find any fix yet. I will post an answer if I find any but currently I am not actively looking for any solution.

Comment: This is so freaking annoying - thanks @Razvan. ill also post answer here if I get a solution.

Comment: Also looking for this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In VS 2017 and newer you can go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> Package Restore
```

And set to false the restores you do not want to happen on project open or save:

[image]

Comment: works on VS pro 2017(v15.3.4), a clean and clever answer ;)

Answer (score 18):

It seems it is not possible to disable this for a specific solution or project, but here is **how you can disable it globally**:

- In VS, go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools
- Disable all search paths, in my case there were four of them

Note that the output window may display some errors during solution loading. In my case it complained about `gulp` not being found. This has no negative effects, however.

All tools work as expected when called from the command line.

Comment: Thank you. I removed only `$(PATH)` and it stopped running it on start.

Comment: s/diaable them all/disable the ones which need to be disabled

Comment: This is the only work-around that I've found. Extremely disappointing that there is not a good solution in VS.

Comment: Now that your comments argon it looks like I am talking to myself. xD

Comment: In VS 2017 it's Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Package Management > External Web Tools

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the bower.json file from your Visual Studio project, but keep it in the project directory to manually run bower.

Comment: Interesting in my case since I used bower to download components to a shared directory where projects pick up files, rather than installing directly into project. Weird, maybe, but more adapted to how we work here.

Comment: This is a great project-level solution. You don't have to change a global setting, and can also check in the change to source control, which might be preferable if you work in teams and on multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case (VS2015), I found a bogus **package.json** file in my project directory.

Removing the **package.json** file stopped bower from trying to run "npm install" every time I opened the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a more up to date solution for this problem, in case someone stumbles upon this post...

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Package Management -> Package Restore

And then turn the appropriate settings to "False".